# Why does post-increment work on wrapper classes

Tags: java, immutability, post-increment

I was doing a review of some code and came across an instance of someone post-incrementing a member variable that was a wrapper class around Integer.  I tried it myself and was genuinely surprised that it works.

```
Integer x = 0; 
System.out.print(x++ + ", ");
System.out.print(x);
```

This prints out `0, 1`, not `0, 0`  as I would have expected.  I've looked through the language specification and can't find anything covering this.  Can anyone explain to me why this works and if it's safe across multiple platforms?  I would have thought that this would decompose into

```
Integer x = 0;
int temp1 = x.intValue();
int temp2 = temp1 + 1;
System.out.println(temp1);
temp1 = temp2;
System.out.println(x.intValue());
```

But apparently there's something in the specification that make it add `x = temp1;` before the last line

Comment: It's not so much a wrapper class around Integer, as it is that x is an instance of class Integer, with the methods/operators that go along with that. One of which is the '++' operator, which increments its value.

Comment: @hd1 - That's not correct. The `++` operator applies only to (primitive) integer types. Behind the scenes, `x` is unboxed, the `++` is applied, and the result is then assigned back to `x` (after a boxing conversion). The `Integer` class does not have a `++` operator. In fact, `Integer` objects are immutable.

Comment: Why would you have expected the output to be `0, 0`?

Comment: @hd1: Java doesn't support operator overloading except in one very specific case (the + operator in Strings).  The Integer class does not have a ++ operator.

Comment: @Ted: it's not self-evident that after unboxing, Java will know to rebox the primitive and put it back into the original variable.

Comment: @Jherico - It is self-evident once you read the spec. (See my answer.) It was designed that way because everyone familiar with the C/C++ family of languages (to which Java is related) expects `++` to change the value of the variable to which it is applied, and having wrapper classes should not conflict with that expectation.

Comment: @Ted - people familiar with C++ might also expect Integer to behave the way a C++ 'const' object would.  I don't think it's particularly intuitive, especially since pre-increment doesn't normally involve a temporary variable.  It certainly doesn't seem to be covered anywhere in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numbers.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: The analogy with a C++ `const` seems flawed. You can't use `++` with a `const int` in C++. So you should expect either to not be able to apply `++` to a Java `Integer` at all, or for it to behave just like an `int`, not a `const int`. (Java tries to make `Integer` behave as much like `int` as possible.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19248/discussion-between-jherico-and-ted-hopp)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's perfectly safe to use across platforms. The behavior is specified in [§15.4.2 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) (emphasis added):

> The result of the postfix expression must be a variable of a type that is convertible ([§5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to a numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> The type of the postfix increment expression is the type of the variable. The result of the postfix increment expression is not a variable, but a value.
>
> At run-time, if evaluation of the operand expression completes abruptly, then the postfix increment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no incrementation occurs. Otherwise, the value 1 is added to the value of the variable **and the sum is stored back into the variable**. Before the addition, binary numeric promotion ([§5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable. If necessary, the sum is narrowed by a narrowing primitive conversion ([§5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)) and/or subjected to boxing conversion ([§5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)) to the type of the variable before it is stored. The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable before the new value is stored.

**EDIT** Here's a more accurate equivalent of what's going on in your example code:

```
Integer x = 0;
int temp = x.intValue();
x = temp + 1; // autoboxing!
System.out.println(temp + ", ");
System.out.println(x.intValue());
```

Comment: +1 "If necessary, the sum is... subjected to boxing conversion"

Comment: Just wanted to add that Integers are immutable, so after this is over x is actually a different Object.

Answer (score 3):

Answer by Sir Tedd Hopp is at a very complex level for programmers who are programming only for few or couple of years.

Let me clear your doubt in simple way
suppose

```
    Integer x=10;
    x++;
    System.out.println(x) ;
```

output will be 11

Because ++ either post or pre increment is doing Addition by 1 only internally

ie x+1 is what it has to perform and put back the result in the same variable.

```
ie x=x+1;
```

now we all know that + operator can only take primitives but x is object ,
then we have auto-unboxing and auto-boxing concept.
so the expression becomes

```
x.intValue()+1;//step 1 auto-unboxing

x=Integer.valueOf(x.intValue()+1);//step 2 auto-boxing
```

Hence output comes as 11 after another step of auto-unboxing inside the println statement.

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 1.5, Java performs auto-unboxing to convert "wrapper types" such as `Integer` to the corresponding primitive type `int` when necessary.  Then the increment operator can work on the resulting `int`.

Comment: I know about auto-unboxing, which is why I'm not surprised that x++ compiles.  What I didn't get is that java apparently will also re-box the incremented variable and stuff it back in the Integer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "new" feature in Java 5 called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) - Integer is transformed to in when needed - and vice-versa. Same applies to Float, Double, Boolean etc.

While it is a convenient feature, it can lead to a HUGE performance hit if you are not careful

Answer (score 0):

Note that the output would be as expected if the increment operation were moved to a method:

```
public void printIncrement(Integer x1) {
    System.out.print(x1++ + ", ");
}
```

That's because Java passed a copy of the reference so you're now working with a new reference object, x1 instead of x. The original Integer object that x was pointing to stays unchanged and x still points to it.

This can easily bite you when doing calculations in a method if you forget about it.