# HashMap with Integer keys and values : Change in values do not get reflected

Tags: java, hashmap

I was trying sample code and some got result which I don't understand:

```
 Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(1, 2);
 System.out.println(map.get(1));
 Integer k = map.get(1);
 k++;
 System.out.println(map.get(1));
```

The result:

```
2
2
```

But as Integer is an object, the change should get reflected in the map value as well? So why is the value *not* changing?

Comment: your understanding is wrong. `Integer` (and all other boxed types) is immutable. `k++` returns a new Integer with the value 3, the original Integer stays 2.

Answer (score 3):

`Integer` is immutable, and `k++` doesn't change the value of the `Integer` stored in the `Map`. It create a new `Integer` instance.

You should put the new value in the `Map` in order for the `Map` to be modified:

```
     Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put(1, 2);
     System.out.println(map.get(1));
     Integer k = map.get(1);
     k++;
     map.put(1, k);
     System.out.println(map.get(1));
```

If `Integer` was a mutable class, and you would have called a method that mutates its state, you wouldn't have needed to put the value again in the `Map`.

Comment: Then how this works :
          Integer h = new Integer(1);
          System.out.println(h);
          h++;
       System.out.println(h);

the output is     
1     
2

Comment: @luk2302 It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280134/why-does-post-increment-work-on-wrapper-classes).

Comment: @JavaBeginner `h++` unboxes the `Integer` to an `int`, increments that `int` and assigns the incremented value back to the `h` variable (which requires boxing the `int` to `Integer`).

Comment: @JavaBeginner Because `h++` only assigns a new value (new Object) to `h`. It doesn't change the value that was already put in the Map.

Answer (score 1):

Misconception on your end: Integer is immutable!

That means that k++ creates a new Integer object. It is impossible to change the value of an existing Integer object!

Comment: Then how this works : 
    Integer h = new Integer(1);
    System.out.println(h); 
    h++; 
   System.out.println(h); 
the output is 1 2